# doctrine querybuilder syntax error expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string

Tags: php, symfony4, doctrine-query, mysql-spatial

Having following error:

**"[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string."**

building this query with doctrine querybuiler :

```
SELECT * 
FROM area 
WHERE ST_Contains(polygon, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(13.405584 52.510621)', 1));
```

(Sf4 and Doctrine 2.6)

Orm config:

```
orm:
    dql:
      numeric_functions:
        ST_Contains: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\STContains
        ST_GeomFromText: App\Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\STGeomFromText
        POINT: CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\MySql\Point
```

STGeoFromText Class:

```
use CrEOF\Spatial\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\AbstractSpatialDQLFunction;

class STGeomFromText extends AbstractSpatialDQLFunction
{
    protected $platforms = array('mysql');

    protected $functionName = 'ST_GeomFromText';

    protected $minGeomExpr = 1;

    protected $maxGeomExpr = 2;
}
```

Construction of the query:

```
use CrEOF\Spatial\PHP\Types\Geometry\Point;

    $lon = 13.405584;
    $lat = 52.510621;
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('a.name')
        ->from(Area::class, 'a')
        ->where("ST_Contains(a.polygon, ST_GeomFromText(':point', 1))")
        ->setParameter('point', new Point($lon, $lat), 'point');
    $result = $query->getResult();
```

same error with:

```
->where("ST_Contains(a.polygon, ST_GeomFromText(:point, 1))")
```

notice no presence of symbol ' wrapping the :point parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from [Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php#L3352), which tries to parse and validate the query build.

The issue is caused by ***the parser not "understanding"*** that **ST_Contains** returns a boolean value and **expects a comparisor operator** which could one of the following "**=, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=**".

To overcome this, add `= true` to your condition:

```
->where("ST_Contains(a.polygon, ST_GeomFromText(:point, 1)) = true")
```